# Is there a NodeJS 'passthrough' stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

Is there a NodeJS 'passthrough' stream?

i.e. an object where whatever I put in to it comes out immediately, unchanged.

It seems pointless, but it would be useful as a 'static centre' for rapidly changing code during development.

Comment: [Maybe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) (0.10+).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks, I'd read that page 20 times, as still missed it.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yeah. Actually, by that very name. :)

> [`stream.PassThrough`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough)

It's available with Node 0.10 and later as part of the [Streams 2 update](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/) (mentioned at the end).

It's also one of the few types from Streams that can be directly instantiated:

```
var pass = new stream.PassThrough();
```

And, it's currently documented briefly under [API for Stream Implementors](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementors) (towards the bottom of the [Steams ToC](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#toc)).

Answer (score 7):

it's really handy when you need to send input bytes of a TCP Server to another TCP Server.

In my microcontroller application's web part i am using this as follows

```
   var net = require('net'),
       PassThroughStream = require('stream').PassThrough,
       stream = new PassThroughStream();

   net.createServer({allowHalfOpen: true}, function(socket) {
     socket.write("Hello client!");
     console.log('Connected:' + socket.remoteAddress + ':' +    socket.remotePort);
     socket.pipe(stream, {end: false});
     }).listen(8080);

   net.createServer(function(socket) {
     stream.on('data', function (d) {
      d+='';
      socket.write(Date() + ':' + ' ' + d.toUpperCase());
    });
   socket.pipe(stream);
   }).listen(8081);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it useful to pipe bytes from one TCP server to the next, if they have to share the same stream reference?

Comment: @Ryan Quin, it is usually done for decoupling and multiple threads. like microservices.